# Can you set a property on a collection of elements declaritively?

Tags: wpf, xaml

If i have a collection of elements in a control (e.g. a custom ItemsControl), can i set a property on all the children of that control through a style in a resource dictionary. For instance i would like to set the visibility on all those elements on a certain trigger. Is this possible decoratively?

Cheers
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, we can use the [ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle.aspx) on an ItemsControl or any derived control to set a style for the contained elements.

```
<Style x:Key="customStyle">
    <Setter Property="Control.Opacity"
            Value=".5" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Control.IsMouseOver"
                 Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Control.Opacity"
                    Value="1" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<ItemsControl ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource customStyle}">
    <ListBoxItem >Item 1</ListBoxItem>
    <sys:String>Automaticly gets Wrapped</sys:String>
    <ListBoxItem>Item 3</ListBoxItem>
</ItemsControl>
```